# Java lib: Analyzer for texts with different semantic

Tags: java, compare, analysis, lexical-analysis

I need a java lib that will compare 2 different texts with some similarities and tell me if they're related or not.

For example, I would compare one of these

a)  **"COMP          150.00 MG X      20.00 UN"**

b)  **"COMP          150.00 MG X      60.00 UN"**

with this one

c)  **"150 mg comp.rec.x 20"**

and the lib should tell me that the first one corresponds and the second doesn't because **a)** and **c)** are both mentioning a medicine which is presented in "150mg capsules and the package brings 20 units" and **b)** refers to a 60 unit pack..

Another thought I had was about regular expressions, but I'm not quite into them so that's why I'm asking for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the structure of those texts? Are the variants always structured in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text variants are always structed in the same way, regular expressions could be one way to solve this. Basically you'd check each text against a set of expressions and see whether they match or not. Depending on how much the variants differ the expressions could be simple or might need to be more complex.

For the case above, the first expression could look like this:

`COMP 150.00 MG X 20.00 UN` -> `(identifier) (capsule weight) X (num units)`

From this the following expression could be derived: 
`^COMP (\d+(?:\.\d+)?) MG X ([\d]+(?:\.\d+)?) UN$` 
(this assumes that the number of spaces are always equal and that you always use `MG` and `UN`).

The second expression:

`150 mg comp.rec.x 20` -> `(capsule weight) comp.rec.x (num packages)`

The following expression could be derived: 
`^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) mg comp\.rec\.x (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$`

You'll see that both expressions contain the following part twice: `([\d]+(?:\.\d+)?)`
 
Those parts capture numbers into a group and allow you to then parse that text into a `Double`, for example.
Here's a short breakdown of that sub-expression:

- `( ... )` is a capturing group, i.e. you can access the part that matches that group directly
- `\d+` means one or more digits
- `\.` is the literal dot
- `(?: ... )` is a non capturing group, i.e. you can apply quantifiers but can't access the matched parts directly

From the above parts you get the following:

- `(?:\.\d+)?` means at most one dot followed by at least one digit. This would match `.123` but not `.1.2.3` or `1.`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` means at least one digit, optionally followed by a dot which is followed by at least one more digit. This would match `1.23`, `12.3` or `123` but not `1.`, `.2` or `1.2.3`.

If you have those expressions, apply the correct one on the text (if you know it, otherwise test first) and extract both groups. Then compare the values of those groups.

Note: don't forget that in Java strings you have to escape backslashes, thus `\d` would be written as `"\\d"` etc.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I'll check it! In the meanwhile if anyone knows how I could achieve this without having to code it myself I would be most apreciated. I'm sure there is a jar somewhere in the web that I could use for this.

Comment: @user1269388 Unless this is a standard format I'd say it is highly unlikely to find a library that provides what you want with any coding or coding like configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Implement Comparable interface and override CompareTo method.
If not found answer please explain question with other example.

Comment: I don't quite get how that would solve the described problem. You'd want to know whether _"COMP 150.00 MG X 20.00 UN"_  and _"150 mg comp.rec.x 20"_ are similar or not. Which one is greater or smaller wouldn't mean much in that case. And even if so, what the OP asks for woudl be the implementation of that comparison.

Comment: Thanks prabhat but my problem is a bit more complicated than that.
What I intend to do is to read two columns from different tables in the DB (which hold data in the format described above) and check which are related. To achieve that, I would need an analyser that could understand that even they don't say the same, they mean the same. Like my example above, where a) and c) are related.